# Amcharts add value to dataset from external source (temperatue)

Tags: javascript, ajax, amcharts

I have a temperature sensor connected over http and I would like to add temperature to the Amcharts every 5 seconds. Have someone some example how to add new value to the current dataset? I will use line chart to represent temperature on y axis and datetime on x

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea behind dynamically updating a chart is to add a new element to your chart's dataProvider then call its `validateData` method. While it doesn't use AJAX, [this demo](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/dynamically-updated-sliding-chart/) basically has the framework laid out for you in the function that is called in the `setInterval` call:

```
setInterval( function() {
  // make your ajax call here, then on a successful callback:
  // add data item to the array
  chart.dataProvider.push( {
    /* new data */
  } );
  chart.validateData();

}, 5000 );
```

It also shifts the old data off the chart, which you may want to consider if you have a lot of data points added to the chart. A regular serial chart's performance will degrade after several hundred to a thousand points or so.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I have done this example but it only shows me one value. Is this because the charData[] (array) contains only one value? (in the generateChartData function)

What I want is to draw a random value each second and push each time the graph to the left side..

here is example (copy/paste)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>chart created with amCharts | amCharts</title>
        <meta name="description" content="chart created using amCharts live editor" />

        <!-- amCharts javascript sources -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>


        <!-- amCharts javascript code -->
        <script type="text/javascript">


            function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
                                                        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
                                                  }
            var chartData = generateChartData();
            function generateChartData() {
                                          var chartData = [];
                                          var firstDate = new Date();

                                          firstDate.setSeconds( firstDate.getDate());

                                             chartData.push( {
                                              date: firstDate,
                                              temp: 0
                                            } );

                                            return chartData;
                                        }


            var timeout;
            setInterval( function() {

              chart.dataProvider.shift();

              var newDate = new Date(); 
              var temp = Math.round( Math.random() * 40 + 100 );

             // dodamo podatek v graf
              chart.dataProvider.push( {
                date: newDate,
                temp: temp
              } );

              if (timeout)
                clearTimeout(timeout);
              timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                chart.validateData();
              });
            }, 1000 );


            var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
                                          "type": "serial",
                                          "theme": "light",
                                          "dataProvider": chartData,
                                          "valueAxes": [ {
                                            "position": "left",
                                            "title": "Temperatura v °C"
                                          } ],
                                          "graphs": [ {
                                            "valueField": "temp"
                                          } ],
                                          "categoryField": "date",
                                          "categoryAxis": {
                                            "minPeriod": "mm",
                                            "parseDates": true
                                          }
                                        } );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" ></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, since you're starting off with one value, shift just removes it in the next call. Omit the chart.dataProvider.shift() call, or, If you want to eventually start removing points, you can wrap that in a check on its length [like in this example](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/816d3455a31ef901cd164edce4e4d538?editors=0010). Note, I changed the minPeriod to "ss" since your data is coming in every second. 

Also, FYI, this should be a comment on my answer with the details edited into your original question, not a new answer as others don't get notifications on new answers.